# Ruby Regex * does not match sequence of characters

Tags: ruby, regex

Why doesn't this regexp match all the `b`s in the string?

```
'abbbbbbb'.match(/b*/)
#=> #<MatchData "">
```

whereas this does:

```
'abbbbbbb'.match(/b+/)
#=> #<MatchData "bbbbbbb">
```

- The definition of `*` is: "The asterisk indicates there is zero or more of the preceding element".
- The definition of `+` is: "The plus sign indicates there is one or more of the preceding element".

The only difference between the two operators then is the number of matches that they make. They should both match 7 `b`s.

Comment: Use rubular.com it has a regex application that you can test regex expressions into. Trying putting the b after the *

Comment: `b*` means 0 or more `b`s. won't there be 2 matches? Nothing and the `bbbb`?

Comment: `'abbbbbbb'[/b*/] => ""` matches an empty string at the beginning of the string. `'bbbbbbb'[/b*/] => "bbbbbbb"`. Note also `'abbbbbbb'.scan(/b*/) => ["", "bbbbbbb", ""]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Arup: Whopps, Cary is right. I was wrong. Sorry.

Comment: @sawa Yes mine also was on wrong track. :-) It was a Regexp _googly_ that I missed. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug and you just answered your question yourself.

`The definition of * is: "The asterisk indicates there is zero or more of the preceding element"`

So `/b*/` matches if there's no b characters at all.

Comment: Ah ha! You're right, thank you. I had been reading it as 'at least 0' and 'at least 1'!

Comment: Well, even that would be wrong. In that case i don't know what i was thinking :D